# Logical test for R's NA in JAGS

Tags: r, jags, r2jags

What is the jags equivalent of R's `is.na()`? I am using r2jags to pass R data objects to jags, and in my jags model, I want to test if an element of a vector contains the equivalent of R's NA value. I don't know what jags "sees" when R says an element is NA.

Comment: Related question on CrossValidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38227/jags-missing-data-error

Comment: @Andrie Thanks for pointing out the related post. I think I'm basically at the step just after that author. I know how I want jags to respond to missing values, I just need to indicate when it needs to take that action. My current approach is to test for missingness in R, and pass jags objects containing a vector of missing indices. This is a bit inconvenient as it makes the jags model rather situation-specific.